# SQL make empty variable select all

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i have a select tag with following options attached.

```
<option value="">All</option>
<option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="Ford">Ford</option>
```

so if have this sql query `"SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carBrand = '$carBrand'"`

but if "All" is chosen i wan't to get all results printed out but instead i get nothing, i thought an empty string would just select everything but guess not, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically build your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars";
if (!empty($carBrand)) {
    $sql .=  " WHERE carBrand = '$carBrand'";
}
```

Of course, this assumes you have alredy *validated* and *escaped* `$carBrand`.